# How the signature level set to the process in Windows 8?

Tags: cryptography, protection, windows-8

From this blog article:

> [Windows PKI Internals (Signing Levels, Scenarios, Root Keys, EKUs & Runtime Signers).](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=146)

Windows 8 instituted the Signing Level, also sometimes referred to as the Signature Level. This undocumented number was a way for the system to differentiate the different types of Windows binaries, something that became a requirement for Windows RT as part of its requirement to prohibit the execution of Windows “desktop” applications.

How this signature level are determined on what basis ? Is that flag passed to CreateProcess or kernel handles this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://2012.ruxconbreakpoint.com/assets/Uploads/bpx/alex-breakpoint2012.pdf:

[image: Signing Levels]

So the signing level is embedded in the signed image's (file's) certificate. There are no special flags passed to `CreateProcess()`, but `PspCreateProcess()` (a kernel function that's executed as a result of `CreateProcess()`) extracts and validates the signing level from the executed image's certificate.

Comment: http://www.nosuchcon.org/talks/2014/D3_05_Alex_ionescu_Breaking_protected_processes.pdf Page 22 :: In Vista, CREATE_PROTECTED_PROCESS was the only flag needed for
CreateProcess to do the right thing
• But in Windows 8.1, how to specify the actual protection level required (type
and signer?)
• Using the new Protection Level Attribute (0x2000B) in the Process/Thread Attribute List   .What about that flag signifies then ?